# For any random variable X, and any $\alpha > 0 $, s>0, $P(X\geq \alpha )\leq e^{-s\alpha }E[e^{sX}]$

Tags: probability

This is my reasoning:

$$P(X\geq \alpha )=1-P(X \geq  \alpha )=1-\alpha$$

$e^{-s\alpha }E[e^{sX}]$ means $Y=X-\alpha$

Then,

$$P(Y \leq y )=P(X- \alpha  \leq y)=P(X \leq y+\alpha )=y+\alpha $$

Since $y+\alpha =1-\alpha $, we have $P(X\geq \alpha )\leq e^{-s\alpha }E[e^{sX}]$

Am I correct?

Comment: Your derivation to me looks full of mistakes and does not make much sense. Or I am not getting it at all...

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not correct. Why is $P(X \leq y+\alpha)=y+\alpha$?

Correct solution: $P(X \geq \alpha)=P(e^{sX} \geq e^{s \alpha} ) \leq \frac 1 {e^{s \alpha} } Ee^{sX}=e^{-s\alpha} Ee^{sX}$ since $P(Y >c) \leq \frac  1 c EY$ for any positive random variable $Y$.

Comment: I referenced an example from my textbook, but it did not sound right to me. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: Chebyshev Inequality states that if X is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma ^{2}$, then $P(|X-\mu |\geq c)\leq \frac{\sigma ^{2}}{c^{2}}$. I don't see how the variance can be derived from the transformation as shown in the solution above? Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: @AmosKu  Different authors use the term Chebyshev's inequality for different forms of the inequality. According to  K L Chung's book my reference to the inequality was correct.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy applied Markov inequality. At least this is the name I know for it. Try to search for it.

Comment: Got it. It is Markov inequality. Not Chebyshev's inequality. Thank you.